# How to track if user make any actions Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I'm creating app with lessons/tests after it and right now I need to create a report card with some information. I want to add column to Users which will track time spent online(without idle time). For example student is pressing any buttons on site(just for example), it means that student is online and the (current_user.online_time should not stop), but if student did nothing more than 5 minutes  - (current_user.online_time should stop). I found a gem [devise lastseenable](https://github.com/ctide/devise_lastseenable), but can't imagine right know how to make it work according to my wishes. Gem tracks when U did any actions only with User(create/update/delete/ or with models which belongs to user), without tracking any other moves. Can someone give me any ideas?

Comment: You have ApplicationController and before_action filters?

Comment: Have you considered just using something like google analytics for this? Do you really need a custom solution to track specific users, with specific rules, across the site?

Comment: My applications will be used by students, I need to track their useful online activity @TomLord

Comment: You can implement a before_action filter on the application controller that just checks if it's a logged in user, if it is, register what route/action. If you have buttons that do non routed stuff (only interact on client side) then you'll need to bind them to make an ajax ping, you can have a route just for that. And there's plenty of stuff you could use outside of your rails app, to keep track, but this should work for your intended use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is certainly possible to put together a simple user tracking feature without using an external gem specifically built for this purpose. Here is a list of the required implementation steps:

**1. Add a `total_time_online` and a `last_seen_at` field to `User`**

- `total_time_online` will contain the number of seconds the user was seen online
- `last_seen_at` will hold the date and time the user last interacted with the site

**2. Add an `active_now!` method to `User`**

This method will be called whenever the user is interacting with the site. It is responsible for incrementing the `total_time_online` value and updating the `last_seen_at` field:

```
class User
  ActivityThreshold = 5.minutes
  # ...
  def active_now!
    time_since_last_activity = [Time.now - last_seen_at, 0].max

    if time_since_last_activity <= ActivityThreshold
      self.total_time_online ||= 0
      self.total_time_online += time_since_last_activity
    end

    self.last_seen_at = Time.now
    save!
  end
  # ...
end
```

This will only increment the `total_time_online` if the last interaction was less than 5 minutes ago.

**3. Call `active_now!` on the current user on every request**

A global `before_action` should do the trick:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  # ...
  before_action :record_user_activity
  # ...
  private
  # ...
  def record_user_activity
    current_user.active_now! if current_user
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for answer! It works fine. We add before action to application controller, but I don't need to record_user_activity on the video watching page in my app. How can I remove before action only for 1 controller?

Comment: Use `skip_before_action` to selectively skip a before action in a particular controller.